# In or for ? "One of my goals" in/for this summer?

Tags: grammar, expressions, prepositions

In or for ? "One of my goals" in/for this summer is to... ?

Does the meaning change if I use for instead of in?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use

> one of my goals *for* this summer

or

> one of my goals this summer

As far as I know, "in" shouldn't be used here.

Comment: Can you explain why "one of my goals this summer" is acceptable ? I have seen it but dont get it at all.

Comment: "This summer" is used in the same way as "today" or "tomorrow".

Comment: oh wow, I didn't know this. How can I learn about this rule?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209266/grammatical-term-for-words-like-yesterday-today-tomorrow?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa has some info

Comment: Or "during the summer" ?